# error while using winrt::implements and winrt::make

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml, c++-winrt, cppwinrt

In C++/WinRT, I have hand-authored some classes like this (NOT using idls):

```
class GenericController: public winrt::Windows::Foundation::IInspectable {
...
}

class BackgroundController1: public winrt::implements<BackgroundController1, GenericController> {
...
}
```

And I create the object like this:

```
auto controller = winrt::make<BackgroundController1>();
```

I am getting the following errors for each of the classes which derives from winrt:implements<BackgroundControllerX, GenericController>:

```
Error   C3668   'winrt::impl::produce_base<D,I,void>::QueryInterface': method with override specifier 'override' did not override any base class methods    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt\winrt\base.h   8016    
Error   C3668   'winrt::impl::produce_base<D,I,void>::AddRef': method with override specifier 'override' did not override any base class methods    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt\winrt\base.h   8021    
Error   C3668   'winrt::impl::produce_base<D,I,void>::Release': method with override specifier 'override' did not override any base class methods   C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt\winrt\base.h   8026    
Error   C3668   'winrt::impl::produce_base<D,I,void>::GetIids': method with override specifier 'override' did not override any base class methods   C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt\winrt\base.h   8031    
Error   C3668   'winrt::impl::produce_base<D,I,void>::GetRuntimeClassName': method with override specifier 'override' did not override any base class methods   C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt\winrt\base.h   8036    
Error   C3609   'winrt::impl::produce_base<D,I,void>::GetTrustLevel': a 'final' function must be virtual    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt\winrt\base.h   8041    
Error   C2440   'initializing': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'GenericController' (compiling source file C:\Users\...\BackgroundController1.cpp)    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt\winrt\base.h   8814
```

This is the output log:

```
error C3668: 'winrt::impl::produce_base<D,I,void>::QueryInterface': method with override specifier 'override' did not override any base class methods
1>        with
1>        [
1>            D=`anonymous-namespace'::BackgroundController1,
1>            I=GenericController
1>        ]
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17763.0\cppwinrt\winrt/base.h(7737): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'winrt::impl::produce_base<D,I,void>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            D=`anonymous-namespace'::BackgroundController1,
1>            I=GenericController
1>        ]
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17763.0\cppwinrt\winrt/base.h(8005): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'winrt::impl::produce<D,I>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            D=`anonymous-namespace'::BackgroundController1,
1>            I=GenericController
1>        ]
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17763.0\cppwinrt\winrt/base.h(7685): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'winrt::impl::producer<D,GenericController,void>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            D=`anonymous-namespace'::BackgroundController1
1>        ]
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17763.0\cppwinrt\winrt/base.h(8829): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'winrt::impl::producers_base<D,std::tuple<GenericController>>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            D=`anonymous-namespace'::BackgroundController1
1>        ]
1>note: see reference to class template instantiation 'winrt::implements<`anonymous-namespace'::BackgroundController1,GenericController>' being compiled
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17763.0\cppwinrt\winrt/base.h(10615): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'winrt::com_ptr<winrt::impl::IContextCallback>' being compiled
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17763.0\cppwinrt\winrt/base.h(10349): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'winrt::com_ptr<winrt::impl::IServerSecurity>' being compiled
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17763.0\cppwinrt\winrt/base.h(10308): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'std::chrono::time_point<winrt::clock,winrt::Windows::Foundation::TimeSpan>' being compiled 
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17763.0\cppwinrt\winrt/base.h(6462): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'winrt::com_ptr<winrt::impl::IMarshal>' being compiled 
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17763.0\cppwinrt\winrt/base.h(210): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'std::array<uint8_t,8>' being compiled
```

Looks like there might be something wrong in the way the classes are written and the way the objects are created. But I am not able to figure out what or why.

Comment: There isn't enough code in your example to reliably deduce what's going wrong. Please share how GenericController was defined. For example, was it authored in IDL, and then projected from winmd, or is it hand-authored? Iis it inheriting from the ABI `::IInspectable`, or is it inheriting from `winrt::Windows::Foundation::IInspectable`?

Comment: Hi Ryan, these are hand-authored classes - no idls here. And GenericController is inheriting from winrt::Windows::Foundation::IInspectable. GenericController also only has a default constructor. Do you want me to post the entire class definition for GenericController? I feel like the issue is with how I have hand-authored these classes.

Comment: I however added more error info.

Comment: You could try to define your GenericController class as below to inherited from IInspectable `struct GenericController : implements <GenericController, Windows::Foundation::IInspectable> {……};` first and then create BackgroundController1 object like this: `BackgroundController1 c{};`  instead of using winrt::make. If you hand-authore them like this, can it work well?

Comment: After applying this, I am getting a different error. I updated the issue description with the error.

Comment: I can't tell what exactly you're trying to accomplish here. `winrt::WF::IInspectable` wasn't designed to be inherited from in this way - it's used either for projections, or as an argument to `winrt::implements` for authoring.

Comment: BackgroundController and GenericController used to be ref classes which have an inheritance relationship in C++/CX world, and the reason it was a ref class is that I needed to save it as Tag on a control. With C++/Winrt, the class stored on the Tag property does not have to be a runtime class, so I figured I can do it with winrt::implements as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/author-apis#if-youre-not-authoring-a-runtime-class

Comment: FayWang's comment solved this issue. The other error I am facing was becasue of something else.